# Glide for Android - Url request is not sent out, no exception

Tags: android, okhttp, android-glide

**Glide Version: 4.7.1
Integration libraries: okhttp 4.7.1**

I am trying to access and image (PNG) on a server but the request is not even sent. Can the URL formation crash the lib without an error message ? Or maybe it's sent but there is neither a failure response in the Request Listener nor a success.

How can i trace the problem ?

I have tried following the execution chain but i can only see the preparation of the request.

I monitor the network with Charles and i can't see the request sent out

I am using a basic GlideApp module call

```
 GlideApp.with(mApplicationContext).load(url).dontAnimate().listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable final GlideException e, final Object model, final Target<Drawable> target, final boolean isFirstResource) {
            // Nothing arrives here
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(final Drawable resource, final Object model, final Target<Drawable> target, final DataSource dataSource, final boolean isFirstResource) {
            // Nothing arrives here
            return false;
        }
    }).into(imageView);
```

Thanks

Comment: which version of glide you are using?

Comment: @EdalatFeizi 4.7.1 - i edited the question to include that, thanks

Comment: have you included permission to use the internet in the manifest?

Comment: @Udit yes, this only happens for two particular url/images. Other images in my app are fine

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured it out.

I was passing an newly created ImageView in code that i was using to store the returned image temporarily. **This had no dimensions**.

This worked fine with the Picasso library, but stopped working when i changed to Glide. So passing a real ImageView that is visible in a layout, works.

Picasso had another issue with PNG's which is why i switched.